# The packages imports and probsoln seem to be incompatible

Tags: import, probsoln

I want to establish lists of exam questions using `probsoln`. To keep things neatly arranged I want to keep the lists separated from the exams as I use a dedicated folder for each term and for each subject. Subjects might share questions.

To include the files in the LaTeX main document I need `import` to drag the files with proper subdirectory calls.

As a minimal demonstration example I isolated the following structure:

```
.
|-test_exam
|     +-main.tex
|-examquestions
      |-sampleFigures
      |    +erdbeeren.jpg
      +-q.tex
      +-mainlocal.tex
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    \subimport*{../examquestions/}{q}
    \useproblem{1}
\end{document}
```

q.tex:

```
\begin{defproblem}{1}%
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=3cm]{sampleFigures/erdbeeren.jpg}
\end{defproblem}
```

mainlocal.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    \input{q}
    \useproblem{1}
\end{document}
```

with main.tex compiled in pdflatex I get:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `sampleFigures/erdbeeren.jpg' not found on input line 9.
```

If I use mainlocal.tex, everything is OK. Therefore, the general structure in q.tex must be OK. I guess, `probsoln` fetches the problem code (from `defproblem`) from a kind of variable and substitutes it at the place of `useproblem`. This would undermine the attempt of `import` to provide the proper directories.
I haven't found anything about that problem while searching the web.

Background: I have quite some experience in writing LaTeX documents, but do not mess with internals.

Edit (Fre Feb 14 19:06:29 CET 2014):

I found an ugly workaround:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\examquestionspath}{../examquestions/}

\begin{document}
    \input{\examquestionspath q}
    \useproblem{1}
\end{document}
```

q.tex:

```
\begin{defproblem}{1}%
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=3cm]{\examquestionspath  sampleFigures/erdbeeren.jpg}
\end{defproblem}
```

This is by far not satisfacory, but will serve me for the time being until a real solution might appear magically from somewhere.